# In Babylonjs is it best to put multiple assets in a .glb or just one?

Tags: gltf, babylonjs

I have several building models that I am loading into a scene that I am going to clone into a town. I want to clone the buildings individually so I can mix them up so it isn't the same 4 buildings next to each other over and over.

If I were doing a 2D app I would probably put a bunch of the assets into a single file as a sprite sheet. Is this the approach to use in Babylonjs with glb files or is it better to do a single asset per file? Looking at the API it seems more suited to one asset per file but I am still very new to it so I may be missing something.

I am also not attached to using glb if there is a better approach.